# How to deal with localized commands lines

Tags: windows, locale, localization

I'm trying to write a python script to run on Windows (XP and up). Now this script calls "schtasks" to schedule some command in the future. The problem is that the script may run on machines with different localizations. So if I want to schedule a task to be executed once at 16:15 on the 26. August 2015, I need to write different commands for different localized machines. For example:

On a Windows XP with german locale, the schtasks call has to look like this:

```
schtasks /sc EINMAL /st 16:15:00 /sd 26.08.2015 /tr <command>
```

On a Windows 7 with english locale, the very same call has to look somehow like this:

```
schtasks /sc ONCE /st 16:15 /sd 08/26/2015 /tr <command>
```

So to write the script in a way to run on every windows machine supporting the needed features (which is the command schtasks), I'd need to write a whole bunch of code dealing with localization.

Is there a way to circumvent this and make windows parse everything in a specific language?

Thanks!

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/506056).

Comment: Ok, so it is likely impossible.